# My laptop has Sudden shut downs, what might be the issue?

Tags: laptop

My laptop keeps turning off after a few minutes after turning it on but when i enter bios menu it doesn't turn off, at first i thought it was overheating issues so i cleaned the fan and applied new thermal paste, but the problem has persisted, Now am trying to reset it but it turns off in the middle of the process,
What help can you guys offer?

Comment: More detail required, to begin; Which OS?

Comment: Windows 10pro , 1909 build

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it's an issue with the motherboard.  If so, it may not be worth fixing, depending on the model.  Are you able to run and diagnostics from the BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: Yes i actually diagnosed it from the BIOS it passes every test, and never shuts down in BIOS

Comment: Windows key, type 'this computer' right click the former "this computer" icon, select Manage in the menu that appears. Find the system logs and check what you have there, There might be some kind of indication....